# pyinstaller: webbrowser.open doesn't work in packaged app

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, python-3.5, pyinstaller

I have a simple app that runs a local Flask web server and opens a web browser to show it on start up using the following command:

```
webbrowser.open('http://localhost:%d' % port, new=2, autoraise=True)
```

When I run it in development mode, this works fine. However, when it's packaged using pyinstaller and run as an executable, I get this:

```
gvfs-open: http://localhost:5000: error opening location: No application is registered as handling this file
```

The order of the browser's web browser will try is the same in both instances:

```
'xdg-open', 'gvfs-open', 'gnome-open', 'x-www-browser', 'firefox'
```

I tried using specific commands using `webbrowser.get(NAME).open` but none worked (except Firefox).

It seems like this is a problem with pyinstaller. Is it possible some sort of environment variables are being lost or not exported to executable?

I'm using Python 3.5.2 and pyinstaller 3.3.1 on Ubuntu 16.04 with the command

```
pyinstaller --add-data="static:static" app.py
```

EDIT: I have confirmed that the environment variables are indeed being changed:

`print('XDG_DATA_DIRS: ' + os.environ.get('XDG_DATA_DIRS', 'not found'))`

yields

`/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop:/var/lib/snapd/desktop`

in development mode and

`SOURCE_DIR/dist/linux/app/share`

in the packaged executable. I'm going to create an issue on the pyinstaller github.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4835