# No application is registered as handling this file in bundled Python program

Tags: python, pyinstaller, bundle, python-webbrowser

I am using Ubuntu 21.04 with Python 3.8, Matplotlitb 3.4.3, pyinstaller 4.5.1 and I would like python program to open `google.com` page in default web browser. There is also matplotlib package (the reason why it's not working, without matplotlib everything is fine).

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
import webbrowser
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1, 2, 4, 8, 16])
plt.show()

webbrowser.open("https://www.google.com/")
```

When I run this program as `./main.py` or `python3 main.py`, everything is ok and Google Chrome is opened. However when I bundle program into executable using pyinstaller:

```
pyinstaller --onefile main.py
```

And run this bundled program as `./dist/main`, following error appears in terminal:

> gio https://www.google.com/: No application is registered as handling this file

When I define `BROWSER` variable before running file, then it work again:

```
export BROWSER=$(which google-chrome) && ./dist/main
```

However, I would like to run program without declaring that variable. Default browser doesn't have to be Chrome and even OS doesn't have to be Linux, but eg. Windows. I found [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56362682/gio-file-tmp-pdf-no-application-is-registered-as-handling-this-file) with similar problem. But when I downgrade matplotlib from 3.4.3 to 3.0.3 is in the link, there is a lot of compatibility errors. So I would like to keep newest matplotlib.

Is there any way fix the *gio* error?

Comment: The documentation for webbrowser is https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html  - looks like you can open a "controller"

Comment: Very similar question here, with no answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51657864/pyinstaller-webbrowser-open-doesnt-work-in-packaged-app

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the problem is caused by various environment variables being messed up. More info here: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3668

As a workaround you might be able to use subprocess to open the `https` URL with its default handler, which should be the default browser:

```
import os
import platform
import subprocess


env = dict(os.environ)
lp_key = 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH'
lp_orig = env.get(lp_key + '_ORIG')
if lp_orig is not None:
    env[lp_key] = lp_orig
else:
    lp = env.get(lp_key)
    if lp is not None:
        env.pop(lp_key)


opener = {'Darwin': 'open', 'Windows': 'start'}.get(platform.system(), 'xdg-open')

subprocess.run((opener, 'https://www.google.com/'), env=env)
```